# How to interactively create links in JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I want to interactively add links to my JointJS based graph.

My idea is to create a small temporary node on `pointerdown` with a link from the original node to this temporary node, drag it on top of another node and on `pointerup` create the real link removing the temporary link and node.

Unfortunately I don't know how to convince the pointer to move the temporary element and not the node on which the `pointerdown` event happened. Any idea?
Thanks!

```
var tmp_obj;
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
    if(evt.button == 1) {
        // Freeze the selected node so it does not move
        paper.findViewByModel(cellView.model).options.interactive = false;

        // Create a small temporary node on top of the selected node
        tmp_obj = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
            position: { x: x, y: y },
            size: { width: 5, height: 5 }
        }

        // Create the link between the original node and the small temporary node

        // And now?
    }
}

paper.on('cell:pointerup', function(cellView, evt, x, y) {

    if(evt.button == 1) {
        // Unfreeze the origin node
        paper.findViewByModel(cellView.model).options.interactive = true;

        // Delete the temporary object (and temporary link)
        tmp_obj.remove()

        // Find the first element below that is not a link nor the dragged element itself.
        var elementBelow = graph.get('cells').find(function(cell) {
            if (cell instanceof joint.dia.Link) return false; // Not interested in links.
            if (cell.id === cellView.model.id) return false; // The same element as the dropped one.
            if (cell.getBBox().containsPoint(g.point(x, y))) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        // create the link from cellView to elementBelow 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can use the magnet feature of JointJS? If you set `magnet: true` on an SVG subelement of a JointJS element, that element becomes active and will allow the user to create a link starting from that element. For example:

```
var r = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 40 },
    attrs: { text: { text: 'basic.Rect', magnet: true } }
});
```

This will make the  element behave like a port.

Comment: Fantastic! Maybe should be documented a little better. Now I have to find a way to prevent the creation of dangling links between a node and nothing.

Comment: @SiliconValley did you ever figure out how to prevent dangling links? (or how to pick them back up and drag onto an element - once it's disconnected, it just changes the shape :()

Comment: I've added magnet: true to every port but I still am unable to start drawing a link and resize cursor is on all the ports and elements

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the dangling links:

```
joint.dia.Paper({ linkPinning: false })
```

Comment: thank you. The documentation and examples are really way under the quality of the code and library

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://stackoverflows.top/tech-stack/questions/39249034/creating-dynamic-links-on-pointerdown-event-jointjs) is a nice solution.

You can combine

```
linkView.startArrowheadMove('target');
```

and

```
evt.data.view.pointermove(evt, p.x, p.y);
```